# Premiere: Creating title text from clip's creation date

Tags: after-effects, premiere, script

So I have lots of short clips of footage documenting a specific event and the time thereafter. I want to automatically generate a title text that displays a text like `XX seconds, XX hours since` where the seconds update as well. Ideally the metadata already available on the source would be considered to compute the time difference.

I've did some digging on Google and it seems like I would need to utilise the Scripting API, but I'm missing some pointers to get started (and copy together relevant code parts).

Any ideas? Would I be better off trying to do this in After Effects?